# Using VS2010 to support a VS2008 application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 will allow you to upgrade a 2008 project and also to target a previous version of the framework, i.e, 3.5.

But I assume that if I were to modify the project in VS2010 that people using only 2008 would have an issue opening the project, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, as far as I know.

Comment: You were the first to confirm. Everyone else up voted for the additional info, since I couldn't distinguish a clear best answer.

Comment: @Brian: you should really put more effort into an answer. This is just a "Yes/No" answer, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can "down-convert" a project back from newer VS versions and it will be loadable in the older version - although there are some newer features that may be lost in the conversion, in most cases it works fine.

The main problem is that you have to convert each time you switch back and forth. You could try something like [this](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm) for converting the projects. Or you can create two versions (2008 and 2010) of the projects and just make sure you keep them in sync if you add/remove files.